# Bokeh plot with datetime period (month-year) on x-axis

Tags: time-series, bokeh, python-datetime

I am new to bokeh/pandas and trying to plot a trend line by using month-year for  x-axis and integer values for y-axis.

My data looks like below:

```
year_month  emp_count
0   2015-09     1450425
1   2015-10     3093811
2   2015-11     3316241
3   2015-12     3308658
4   2016-01     3402191
```

To plot using bokeh I am converting both columns to ndarray. When i convert year-month column to ndarray, it shows each value as a Period. I have used to_period('M') method to get year_month out of a date column.

```
    temp_df.year_month.values
>>output
    array([Period('2015-09', 'M'), Period('2015-10', 'M'),
           Period('2015-11', 'M'), Period('2015-12', 'M'),
           Period('2016-01', 'M'), Period('2016-02', 'M'),
```

So when i plot using this data, i get following error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'Period' is not JSON serializable

To avoid this error i converted year_month column type to string but i still get the same error. My complete code looks like below:

```
temp_df.year_month = temp_df.year_month.astype(str)
output_file('trend1.html')
p = figure(title='Employee trend', 
           plot_width=800, 
           plot_height=350,
           x_axis_label='Month-Year', y_axis_label='No of Employees', 
          x_axis_type='datetime')

p.line(x= temp_df.year_month, 
       y = temp_df.emp_count)

show(p)
```

Does anyone know how to plot year-month on x-axis using bokeh?

Comment: Does this post solve the question? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611233/using-months-in-x-axis-in-bokeh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by an alternate approach. Thanks to @Samira for inspiration.

I extracted the year-month from date object and defaulted day to '1'.

```
    df = df.join(df.as_of_date.apply(lambda x : pd.Series({
    'day': x.day, 
    'year':x.year, 
    'month': x.month, 
    'year_month': x.to_period('M'),
    'year_month_01': pd.datetime(x.year,x.month,1)
})))
```

After that used 'year_month_01' on axis and bokeh graph looks as expected.

[bokeh graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MdvO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the problem. You should convert the column to date time.

```
df['year_month']=pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'])
```

This should change your column values to as below (day is defaulted to 01):

```
   year_month      emp_count
0   2015-09-01     1450425
1   2015-10-01     3093811
2   2015-11-01     3316241
3   2015-12-01     3308658
4   2016-01-01     3402191
```

Then the plot would work. I tested it on a dummy value as output is below.

```
Value   month_year
2   2018-11-01
3   2018-01-01
4   2018-02-01
5   2018-05-01


sample=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('sample.csv'))
sample['month_year']=pd.to_datetime(sample['month_year'])
p = figure(title='Employee trend', 
           plot_width=800, 
           plot_height=350,
           x_axis_label='Month-Year', y_axis_label='No of Employees', 
          x_axis_type='datetime')

p.scatter(x= sample.month_year, 
       y = sample.Value)

show(p)
```

[image: Output]

Let me know if this works.
Thanks

Comment: Samira, in your example data is read from csv and probably its in string format and string is converted to datetime. In my case I have pandas period object. When i convert it to datetime, I get exception:
"TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime"